# GeoServer + ArcMap

Tags: arcmap, geoserver, wms, geotiff-tiff

I need to setup GeoServer and access GeoTIFF images in the ArcMap. I have started with installing Geoserver and created a layer with GeoTIFF. Now, what are the next steps to publish the map(using WMS) and access them in the ArcMap.

Can anyone please help me in this?

Comment: My first thought is why go through this process to begin with?  ArcMap can read GeoTIFF directly.  Based on your comment below, you are running this on your local machine, so you are doubling up the processor load to simply switch between ArcMap readable formats.  Is this a data quantity issue?  Would it make more sense to use a Raster Catalog, etc, or is this a test for a wider deployment?  Including detail like this will likely help you obtain a better answer.

Answer (score 1):

.

first of all you should read Publishing a GeoTIFF via GeoServer [here](http://workshops.opengeo.org/geoserver-intro/data/geotiff.html#publishing-a-geotiff). then Publishing a layer as wms [here](http://workshops.opengeo.org/geoserver-intro/data/geotiff.html#publishing-a-layer).

> GeoServer can also publish raster imagery. This could be simple
>   georeferenced-images (such as blue marble imagery) all the way to
>   multi-band DEM (digital elevation model) data. In this section, we
>   will load a simple GeoTIFF containing shaded relief for land area. The
>   layer uses standard tri-band RGB values (0-255).

[image: geoserver]

second is that you should read Using WMS service layers [here](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00sp0000001n000000.htm) and [here](http://forum.gina.alaska.edu/forums/1/topics/4). Web Mapping Service (WMS) services can be used in ArcMap (as well as in ArcScene and ArcGlobe) as map layers.

Adding Geospatial Data from a Web Mapping Service (WMS) in ArcMap, you can use this ways:

- From Add Data button (use Go to Home Folder button) GIS Servers > Add WMS Server
- From Catalog (use Go to Home Folder button) GIS Servers > Add WMS Server
- in Table of Contents, right click on Layers and select Add Data > GIS Servers > Add WMS Server

more information you can check out [here](http://magic.lib.uconn.edu/help/help_WMS.htm).

[image]

i hope it helps you...

Comment: Thanks a lot for your quick response. I just did exactly the same and I am able to see the published map on the IE. But when I try to open/add WMS layer into ArcMap, I am geeting an error "Connection Error". I am using "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/nurc/wms?" in the ArcMAP.
Where I am doing wrong? Do I need to install any other software apart from geoserver to publish the maps towards ArcGIS

Thanks again for your quick help.

Kind regards,
Srinivas

Comment: Ok, let me explan you the overview. I have local cache tiles of 500GB, now I want them to publish using WMS + Geoserver to access them in the ArcMap. Do you have nay idea?